# Stopping Code until AJAX call completes inside $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I have a function that loads HTML from an external file via an `AJAX` call using jQuery.

These ajax call runs inside of a `$.each` loop and I need this ajax call to finish before the loop continues. Here is my code:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var cotainer_html = $('.cotainer_html').clone();
    /* Get Image Content */
    $.ajax({
       url: '/assets/ajax/get_studio_image.php',
       type:'GET',
       success:function(data){
          cotainer_html.find('.replaceme').replaceWith(data);
       }
    });
});
```

I know I can set `async:false` but I hear that is not a good idea. Any ideas?

Comment: async: false is the easiest way.  You could also use this library:  https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: ***Never, ever use `async: false`*** It locks the UI thread of the browser until the request completes, which makes it look like it has crashed to the user. It is terrible practice. Use callbacks.

Comment: @stackErr synchronous calls (outside of webworkers) are in the [process of being deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) - some browsers are already logging warnings, the spec already allows for them to experiment with throwing errors - I wouldn't write any new code that uses it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks! I didn't know that. Just deleted my answer.

Comment: @Vesse thanks, your right this is pretty much the same question. I looked all over and missed that. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for clarification around the async issue. I'm going to avoid it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can put each request in to an array and `apply()` that array to `$.when`. Try this:

```
var requests = [];
$('img').each(function(){
    var cotainer_html = $('.cotainer_html').clone();
    /* Get Image Content */
    requests.push($.ajax({
       url: '/assets/ajax/get_studio_image.php',
       type:'GET',
       success:function(data){
          cotainer_html.find('.replaceme').replaceWith(data);
       }
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    console.log('all requests complete');
});
```

Note that you're replacing the same content on each request, so the only one which will have any effect on the UI is the last request. The preceding ones are redundant.

Also note that you should ***never, ever use `async: false`***. It locks the UI thread of the browser until the request completes, which makes it look like it has crashed to the user. It is terrible practice. Use callbacks.

> The OP appears to want the calls to run in series, not in parallel

If this is the case you could use recursion:

```
function makeRequest($els, index) {
    var cotainer_html = $('.cotainer_html').clone();
    $.ajax({
       url: '/assets/ajax/get_studio_image.php',
       type:'GET',
       success:function(data){
          cotainer_html.find('.replaceme').replaceWith(data);
          if ($els.eq(index + 1).length) {
              makeRequest($els, ++index);
          } else {
              console.log('all requests complete');
          }
       }
    });
}

makeRequest($('img'), 0);
```

Comment: The OP appears to want the calls to run in series, not in parallel

Comment: Note that your serial code has no way of indicating to the caller that it has finished...

Comment: This looks great, let me do some testing this afternoon and I'll get back with you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan putting a "console.log" line isn't the same as allowing the function to be used properly asynchronously ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo-recursive loop:

```
var imgs = $('img').get();

var done = (function loop() {
    var img = imgs.shift();
    if (img) {
        var cotainer_html = $('.cotainer_html').clone();
        /* Get Image Content */
        return $.get('/assets/ajax/get_studio_image.php')
         .then(function(data) {
            cotainer_html.find('.replaceme').replaceWith(data);
        }).then(loop);
   } else {
       return $.Deferred().resolve();  // resolved when the loop terminates
   }
})();
```

This will take each element of the list, get the required image, and `.then()` start over until there's nothing left.

The *immediately invoked function expression* itself returns a `Promise`, so you can chain a `.then()` call to that that'll be invoked once the loop has completed:

```
done.then(function() {
    // continue your execution here 
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is pretty creative, I really like it a lot. Let me play around with it and I'll let you know how it turns out.